# Transfer routed event from panorama to tile

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a app in Metro Style, and in  it one page contain the "Panorama" that contain multiple tiles.

In panorama.cs
the event

```
 protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {}
```

and

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{}
```

are used to scroll the panorama from left to right and vice versa.

On each "Tile" I have  defined a function

```
private void Tile_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{}
```

this is used to open another form.

but due to panorama events, this method is not called and if I comment the above events of "Panorama.cs" I am unable to scroll left to right and vice-versa. How to achieve both.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some RnD and hit and trial testing I found this can be done simply.
Instead of using "`MouseDoubleClick`" event handler , just use "`PreviewMouseDoubleClick`". 
:)